# Error when returning array object

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I have a problem when returning an array object and then display it to the user, please look at the demo code. A basic snippet but it has the same idea has been, I just can't post the very long code here.

```
Class foobar{
   public function foo()
   {
     return array( 'bar' => 'value' );
   }
}
```

This php code was used by another class

```
Class foobar_fetcher{
   public function getFoo()
   {
     $fb = new foobar();
     $result = $fb->foo();
     return $result;
   }
}
```

foobar_fetcher is again called by a main executioner file( ajaxdispatcher.php ) - with a json header.

```
if( isset( $_POST['fetch'] ) ){
   $httpresponse = new stdClass();
   $fb_fetch = new foobar_fetcher();
   $httpresponse->data = $fb_fetch->getFoo();
}

echo json_encode( $httpresponse );
```

Finally this ajaxdispatcher was called by a jquery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajaxdispatcher.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {fetch:'fetch'},
  success: function( data ){
      if( data ) console.log( data );
  }
});
```

Now, the when I try to print out the data , it has no response from the server.
But when I change the return value of the foo() under foobar Class to an integer or string. Things will work fine.

Comment: Cant reproduce, seems to work, is this the actual code? or pseudo : http://codepad.org/yAv7aX2J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to change you ajaxdispatcher to accept a GET request and navigate there from a browser to see what is returned.

```
if( isset( $_GET['fetch'] ) ){
   $httpresponse = new stdClass();
   $fb_fetch = new foobar_fetcher();
   $httpresponse->data = $fb_fetch->getFoo();
}

echo json_encode( $httpresponse );
```

Navigate to /ajaxdispatcher.php?fetch=fetch

Comment: I have already tried this method. It works fine. But when displaying it to the ajax, it has no response.

Comment: What browser are you using?  If you are using Chrome, you can inspect the request and response and see where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I would do that may improve your chances of success

1. Set appropriate HTTP headers and `exit` immediately after sending your JSON code

   ```
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($httpresponse);
   exit;
   ```

   Also make sure you haven't sent any data to the output buffer prior to this.
2. Tell jQuery the data-type to expect

   ```
   $.ajax({
       dataType: 'json',
       // and the rest
   ```
3. Add an `error` callback

   ```
   $.ajax({
       // snip
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: @KennethPalaganas So what was the problem?